# Why is Green Glue used so much in the USA, but hardly used at all in the UK?

Tags: sound-proofing

I have been looking at designed for sound proofed walls, it seems that Green Glue is part of a lot of USA design, but does not seem to be used much in the UK.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I don't know how many new homes and remodels I have been a part of but I have seen green glue less than 5 times.  I am in the middle of the US.

Comment: It's not common in my part of the Western US either

Comment: Never heard of it before. No reason I should have, but I think "used a lot" may mean "it was favored by the guys I was working with".

Comment: Sometimes when a question is asked, it helps to know what is being talked about. I'm assuming you are referring to [Green Glue Noiseproofing Compound](http://www.greengluecompany.com/) which is basically dumdum in a tube, an elastomeric goo that can be used between layers of sheetrock to provide sound deadening?

Answer (score -1):

Probably because it is made by the evil French frogs across the channel.

In all seriousness, though, Green Glue is widely available in the UK ([Green Glue.co.uk](http://www.greenglue.co.uk/))